# Efficient approach for calculating Perimeter Of Ellipse

Tags: conic-sections

There are many formulas for calculating the perimeter of an ellipse but the most accurate ones are very lengthy with big infinite series.

I want to ask if there is any simpler proof. Any help is appreciated

Comment: There isn't any closed form, only integral form (which can only be evaluated numerically) and approximations.

Comment: see here http://www.ams.org/notices/201208/rtx120801094p.pdf

Comment: If there were a simpler way, why would anyone produce those infinite series?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: those series can be manipulated in order to produce nice and tight algebraic inequalities, which are more practical for many purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us define, for some $p>0$, the order-$p$ mean between two positive numbers $a,b$ as
$$ M_p(a,b) = \sqrt[p]{\frac{a^p+b^p}{2}}. $$
If $a,b$ are the lengths of the semiaxis of an ellipse, the perimeter $L$ of the ellipse fulfills
$$2\pi\cdot M_{\frac{\log 2}{\log(\pi/2)}}(a,b) \geq L \geq 2\pi\cdot M_{\frac{3}{2}}(a,b)\qquad (\text{Muir,Alzer,Qiu}) $$

A couple of paragraphs of [my notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view) are devoted to this interesting problem, related to [complete elliptic integrals of the second kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteEllipticIntegraloftheSecondKind.html) and continued fractions. We also have
$$ L\approx \pi\left[3(a+b)-\sqrt{(a+3b)(b+3a)}\right]\qquad (\text{Ramanujan}) $$
which is pretty accurate.

Comment: Just a comment that the accuracy of [R] approx falls off for $b \ll a$

Answer (score 0):

consider the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$,$\implies$ upper half is given by the formula, $y=\frac{b}{a}\sqrt{a^2-x^2}.$

Then  $$Perimeter=2\int_{-a}^{a}\sqrt{1+\frac{dy}{dx}^2}dx$$

Comment: OK, now,how do you propose to evaluate that integral?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think need to go for numerical integral. I tried to solve via normal approach. I failed.

Comment: I substituted $t=\frac{x}{a}$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature

Comment: can I do like this?

Comment: Well, you have to use some kind of numerical approach. I don't know which kind to recommend.